# Increment parameter in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, each, increment

I have an API call that needs to be made in "chunks" (due to API limits). I'd then loop through that data.

All of this happens in a rake task.

Here's the loop:

```
Stripe::Event.all(:count => 100, :offset => 0).each do |event|

end
```

But I need to increment the `offset` parameter by 100 (ie. 100, 200, 300) to actually be able to loop through all the events.

So what's the best way to increment that `offset` parameter within the rake task?

Comment: In the first call to rake task, offset would be 0; 2nd time you call rake task, offset should be 100; and so on. Is it like that?

Comment: @JatinGanhotra Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Stripe::Event is an ActiveRecord model, I think you are looking for:

```
Stripe::Event.find_in_batches(:batch_size => 100).each do |batch|
  batch.each do |event|
    ...
  end
end
```

Otherwise I think you could look at http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_in_batches for inspiration on how to solve this problem.

The most straight forward would be something like

```
events = "not blank"
count = 100
offset = 0
until events.blank? do
  events = Stripe::Event.all(:count => count, :offset => offset)
  events.each do |event|

  end
  offset += count
end
```